# Drawing artefacts when resizing a NSScrollView quickly with autolayout

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, nstableview, nsview, nssplitview

As shown below I have a NSScrollView with 2 panels (3 actually but not shown in the image). I am wondering if this is simply a performance issue or something more erroneous to do with auto layout?

[image: Resizing snap-shots.]

Neither of the views are particularly complicated or have very complicated constraints. The left view hierarchy is,

```
Left NSSplitView's view
  |-- Custom view     NB lowered the trailing priority here... view]-(0@250)-|
      |--NSTextField
      |--NSTableView
```

The most advanced thing I did was to lower the priority which attaches the container view to the superview. this is because I want the panel to be able to cover up the left hand side without the left hand side resizing. When the divided is fully to the left the views there still have the same size it's just that the right panel now is above the view left panel's views.

**Is there a better way to achieve this effect?**

**What could be causing this drawing artefact?**

Comment: Looks like your custom view isn't properly redrawing the invalidated content..? I'd suspect the same glitch will occur when not using auto layout.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Your comment made me look at the images a bit closer and I noticed that the artefacts only appear in the table view. Its as if the table view doesn't have time to redraw it's area when the divider moves. I will make a mock application and post the code here.